# returning different data based on oAuth status

Tags: javascript, angular, express, oauth

I'm trying to use 0auth with a callback that automatically appends the token to the end of the request... so it properly denies access in my `todo` service. I want to use the same `getTodos()` method to return a different API endpoint if the authorization is not met... how do I return the `publictodosURL` endpoint data instead of the `todosURL` endpoint data if the `getTodos()` catches a 401 error in the pipe?

essentially I want the user who is not authenticated to view the `publictodosURL` and if they are logged in and authenticated they will get the the `todosURL` data returned.

```js
export class TodoService {

  private todosURL = 'http://localhost:3001/api/todos';
  private publictodosURL = 'http://localhost:3001/api/public/todos';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTodos() {
    return this.http
      .get<Todo[]>(this.todosURL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
      );
  }

  //MAYBE BY CHECKING THE ERROR HERE? AND THEN SOMEHOW RETURN get(<Todo[]> 
       //(this.publictodosURL) 
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', err);
    return throwError(err.message || err);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are logged in then you must have token returned from oAuth.

check for token 

if the token is present then call todosURL otherwise call publictodosURL

Comment: I'm just getting into oAuth so I honestly do not know how to check if a token is present... your answer obviously makes sense besides my inability to do it. rip

Comment: do I import the auth service?

Comment: How you are authenticating? It must be an API which checks if the user is registered then it will return token.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/ is the tutorial I have been following... BUT I haven't authenticated in any way yet... but I want this to server the unauthenticated response. Maybe it's not possible in the way that this tutorial has the auth.service setup?

Comment: so the route is protected already which is why I get a 401... and I have setup the auth service in my project. I want users who don't register/login to be able to follow the same html links and just receive different endpoints

Comment: if this is too much of a shitshow and not structured right for this end goal ... feel free to say that and I will just continue to learn more about it ! (this is why I hate tutorials because I always try to fit some sort of my own functionality in and I'm not entirely sure if it's set up right for that)

Comment: no, you may achieve it.